# How do I get the host url in post file?

Tags: jekyll

The question is in `jekyll`.I put my images resource into `assets/images/` folder.And I want to refer this image in my post file. 
The site give these [solution](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/):

```
... which is shown in the screenshot below:
![My helpful screenshot]({{ site.url }}/assets/screenshot.jpg)
```

But how do I know the the host instead of `site.url`? So it will work fine in local and github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that the site is wrong. Calling an image can be done like this :

```
![My helpful screenshot]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/screenshot.jpg)
```

Don't forget to set your `baseurl` depending on your hosting.

eg : if your site is at `username.github.io/myblog`, set `baseurl: /myblog`

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll is static site generator, destination result of this generator is located on **_*site*** folder, on this folder we can find result of assets, css, javascript and html which generated from ***_post*** folder. ***Site*** is one of the variable to collect Sitewide information and configuration settings from  ***_config.yml***. Url can set on _config.yml